# ERROR: could not establish encrypted connection , QT-SslServer

Tags: c++, qt, server, qtcpsocket, qsslsocket

I start to study this code, but...

**There are some issues:**

CLIENT SIDE:
ERROR: could not establish encrypted connection (The remote host closed the connection)

SERVER SIDE:
Now listening on 0.0.0.0:22333
New connection
ERROR: could not receive message (Network operation timed out)

How can i resolve it?
Thanks...

**This is the original code:**
https://github.com/GuiTeK/Qt-SslServer

Comment: You may have a firewall preventing the connection.

Comment: It also won't work if you did not copy the .pem and .key files according to the documentation.